# Map function only mapping first object not mapping all objects.(React)

Tags: reactjs

I am currently cloning Instagram for practicing react.js. I almost finished this small practice with StackOverflow users' help. Really appreciate it. For now, I tried to make several feeds by using the map method because it repeats the same process. However, it only shows the first object in JSON file. Could you check my code and which part is wrong? I checked that whan I console.log the json.the file shows all three objects. However, the map function only take one object from json file.
In advance, I really appreciate your help!

This is Feed.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';
import {
  FaRegHeart,
  FaRegComment,
  FaRegPaperPlane,
  FaRegBookmark,
  FaEllipsisH,
} from 'react-icons/fa';
import Comment from '../../../compoonents/Comment/Comment';

class Feed extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      feedInfo: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/FeedInfo.json', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          feedInfo: data,
        });
      });
  }
  getValue = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  addComment = () => {
    this.setState({
      commentList: this.state.commentList.concat([this.state.value]),
      value: '',
    });
  };

  addCommEnter = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.addComment();
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.feedInfo);
    return (
      <div className="feeds">
        {/* {(this.feedList || []).map((article, i) => { */}
        {this.state.feedInfo.map((feedInfo, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="article" key={i}>
              <div className="identi">
                <img
                  className="selfi-identi"
                  alt="selfi-img"
                  src={feedInfo.selfiImg}
                />

                <span className="name"> {feedInfo.id} </span>

                <div className="faEllipsisH">
                  <FaEllipsisH />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="pic">
                <img id="feed-pic" src={feedInfo.feedImg} />
              </div>
              <div className="show-box">
                <div className="reaction-icons">
                  <FaRegHeart className="heart" />
                  <FaRegComment className="comment" />
                  <FaRegPaperPlane className="plane" />
                  <FaRegBookmark className="bookMark" />

                  {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="heart" />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} className="comment" />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} className="plane" />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookmark} className="bookMark" /> */}
                </div>

                <div className="like-counts">
                  <span>like 4,000</span>
                </div>

                <div className="check-comments">
                  {/* <span>{this.articleicle[i].descirbtion}</span> */}
                  <a id="space" href="">
                    expanding
                  </a>
                  <br />
                  <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                  <ul className="feed-comments">
                    <Comment commentAddList={feedInfo.comment} />
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="comment">
                <i className="fa fa-smile-o" />
                <input
                  // onChange={this.textChange}
                  // onKeyPress={this.enterClick}
                  onKeyPress={this.addCommEnter}
                  onChange={this.getValue}
                  className="user-input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Add Comment..."
                  value={this.state.value}
                
                />
                <button onClick={this.addComment} className="post">
                  Post
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Feed;
```

This is FileInfo.json file

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "id": "test",
    "selfiImg": "/image/about.png",
    "feedImg": "/image/ucscPic.png",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "wecode",
        "content": "Welcome to world best coding bootcamp!",
        "isLiked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "joonsikyang",
        "content": "Hi there.",
        "isLiked": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "userName": "jayPark",
        "content": "Hey.",
        "isLiked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "id": "test",
    "selfiImg": "/image/about.png",
    "feedImg": "/image/ucscPic.png",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "wecode",
        "content": "Welcome to world best coding bootcamp!",
        "isLiked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "joonsikyang",
        "content": "Hi there.",
        "isLiked": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "userName": "jayPark",
        "content": "Hey.",
        "isLiked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "id": "test",
    "selfiImg": "/image/about.png",
    "feedImg": "/image/ucscPic.png",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "wecode",
        "content": "Welcome to world best coding bootcamp!",
        "isLiked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "joonsikyang",
        "content": "Hi there.",
        "isLiked": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "userName": "jayPark",
        "content": "Hey.",
        "isLiked": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: All 3 objects are the same in your .json file. Only their keys are different.

Comment: I will change the content when I arrive home! But I think it wold be show three feeds whatever the inside object content because we have three objects

Comment: The code looks fine, what exactly is the issue? Could you provide a reproduction link on https://codesandbox.io/?